# Find the point on the plane x + 2y + 3z = 4 that is closest to the point (1, 1, 2) using Lagrange Mulipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know how to solve this problem "normally" (using vector methods) but I don't know how to solve it using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Your constraint function is $g(x,y,z)=x+2y+3z$. The most convenient objective function is the square of the distance to $(1,1,2)$ i.e. $f(x,y,z)=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-2)^2$. Lagrange multipliers tells you to consider the system of four equations in four unknowns, consisting of the constraint equation and $2(x-1)=\lambda,2(y-1)=2\lambda,2(z-2)=3\lambda$. If you solve each of these three equations for $x,y,z$ respectively, then you can plug them into the constraint to get an equation only involving $\lambda$.

Comment: To Ian,bnslug would you like to explain me how can I solve using vector method,Thanks

Comment: @juantheron You use vector projection, take any point on the plane and find the vector (by subtraction) between it and the given point, then project that vector onto the normal for the plane. Then add that to the given point to "push" it onto the plane and that will be your point. The answer is 9/14, 4/14, 13/14